# Chrome - Gdk: gdk_window_set_user_time called on non-toplevel

Tags: gnome, chrome

Running Chrome in GNOME (3), at lest from shell, yield this error for each key-press issued in the browser:

```
[...:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(209)] 
 Gdk: gdk_window_set_user_time called on non-toplevel
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue with `xim`. Not sure what. To silence do:

```
$ unset GTK_IM_MODULE
$ google-chrome
```

this one is set to `xim`.

(AFAIK) When not set GTK will automatically choose a suitable immodule.

*Any better solutions and / or explanations on the issue is welcome.*